What changes were introduced in the new image uploader, and are not considered bugs?
I'm aware of:

160px minimum image size limit.
For PNG files above some KB threshold, the new image uploader attempts to compress them into a smaller PNG file (same dimension but higher compression), instead of directly converting into a jpg. But they can't be compressed enough, they're converted to jpg. By comparison, the old image uploader always convert png to jpg if above some KB threshold.
sstatic.net images aren't displayed on (some?) other sites outside the SE network.
The new image uploader is slower than the old image uploader.

What other changes were introduced in the new image uploader, which are by design, at least in the current stage of implementation?


new image uploader = upload to https://i.sstatic.net/
old  image uploader = upload to https://i.stack.imgur.com/


It's apparently blocked in China, so no change there at present.

For those who can’t see the deleted answer, no hotlinking (offsite links) allowed

being blocked in china is strange - sstatic is SE's own domain, and is used for other things too. Also - I suspect the minimum size limit is a bug, not a feature

I live in China.  I turned off "workarounds" (VPNs, proxies, etc.) and made this video looking at (uncached) images: i.sstatic.net worked for me (yay!), i.stack.imgur.com remains nonfunctional (so some images work, and others don't work).  Gravatar and Google are still nonfunctional.  (If I upload an image, it uploads to Imgur.)

Thanks @Shadow, good point, it's a better title.
